# Analyzing execution of a Python program from another Python program

Tags: python, debugging, subprocess, dynamic-analysis

I want to write a Python program that analyzes the execution of other arbitrary Python programs.

For example, suppose I have a Python script called `main.py` that calls a function `func` a certain number of times. I want to create another script called `analyzer.py` that can "look inside" `main.py` while it's running and record how many times `func` was called. I also want to record the list of input arguments passed to `func`, and the return value of `func` each time it was called.

I cannot modify the source code of `main.py` or `func` in any way. Ideally `analyzer.py` would work for any python program, and for any function.

The best way I have found to accomplish this is to have `analyzer.py` run `main.py` as a subprocess using pdb.

```py
script = "main.py"
process = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-m', 'pdb', script], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I can then send pdb commands to the program via the process' stdin and then read the output via stdout.

To retrieve the input parameters and return values of `func`, I need to

1. Find the line number of the first line of `func` by analyzing its file
2. Send a breakpoint command for this file/lineno
3. Send continue command
4. Import pickle, serialize `locals()`, and print to stdout (to get input parameters)
5. Send return command (go to end of function)
6. Serialize `__return__` and print to stdout
7. Send continue command

I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of controlling pdb with pipes, you can just [configure your own trace function using `sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) before doing `import main`. (Of course you can also do `importlib.import_module("main")` or `runpy.run_module()` or `runpy.run_path()`.)

For instance,

```
import sys


def trace(frame, event, args):
    if event == "call":
        print(frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_locals)


sys.settrace(trace)

# (this is where you'd `import main` to cede control to it)

def func(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c


func(1, 2, 3)
func("a", "b", "c")
```

prints out

```
func {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
func {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. To get return values, I needed to create another trace function and return it from the main trace function whenever the main trace function was called for the function I'm trying to analyze